# How can I keep these hook mounting screws tight?

Tags: screws, mounting

I have four hooks from ikea and one periodically has the main hook part come off the screws that attach it to the mounting plate. Should I use adhesive to ensure the screws won’t come loose, or replace the screws?
[image: hook and Mount plate]

[image: assembled hook]

Comment: put nail polish on the screws

Comment: @jsotola Please add an answer instead of a comment. Refer to the section **When _shouldn't_ I comment?** on [Comment everywhere](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). Protip: you can earn reputation faster that way.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing you can use is threadlocker, which is a special glue designed to keep screws from coming out. A drop on the threads keeps them from slipping. There are different grades and colors, you'd probably want blue.

If you don't want to buy threadlocker you can try a drop of superglue. One of the comments say you can try nail polish, I haven't had much success with that trick but if you have it on hand you could give it a try.

Comment: Well... a spot weld might be _best_, but it would probably be overkill. :) +1